# Reduce array of directions to increase efficiency

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working through a programming exercise that passes an array of  equidistant directions (N, S, E, W). The objective is to reduce the given array into a more efficient set of directions. For example: Given an `array ["N", "S", "N", "S"],` ultimately, we would arrive back at our point of origin. With the goal of minimizing waste the new array would be not to move or zero.

Approach:

```
function dirReduc(arr) {
  var dx = 0;
  var dy = 0;
  var newArr = ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST"];

  for(var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    switch(arr[i]) {
      case 'NORTH': dy++;
        break;
      case 'SOUTH': dy--;
        break;
      case 'EAST': dx++;
        break;
      case 'WEST': dx--;
        break;
     }
  }
  if() {

  }
}
```

To determine what the new array should be, I've used a switch statement to count each direction object. I was okay with this approach until I got to writing the `if` statements. I want to avoid using excessive conditionals as it seems like a heavy-handed solution.  If `dx` is positive, West is removed from `newArr`, but if `dx` is negative, East will be removed. If `dx = 0`, East and West are removed from `newArr`. Similar conditions will be applied to the N/S objects. **How can I produce the new array without using so many conditionals?**

Answer (score 1):

A very direct, easy to understand way to do this is to simply count the number of times each direction appears, then subtract n from s and w from e. Then make a new array based on these numbers. For example:

```js
let arr = ['n', 'n', 's', 'e', 'w', 'n', 's', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'w']

let counts = arr.reduce((a, c) => (a[c]++, a), {n:0, s:0, w:0, e:0})
let ns = counts.n - counts.s // will be negative if overall south, positive if north.
let ew = counts.w - counts.e
// make array
let result = [...Array(Math.abs(ns)).fill(ns > 0 ? 'n' : 's'), ...Array(Math.abs(ew)).fill(ew > 0 ? 'w' : 'e')]
console.log(result)
```

If all directions balance (i.e. you return to where you start), this will result in an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

If it's about the conditional syntax, you can use a `Reduce` based on `function` instead of `switch/case`.

```js
function dirReduc(arr) {
  const map = {
    NORTH: ([x, y]) => [x, y + 1],
    SOUTH: ([x, y]) => [x, y - 1],
    EAST: ([x, y]) => [x + 1, y],
    WEST: ([x, y]) => [x - 1, y],
  };

  console.log(arr.reduce((tmp, x) => map[x](tmp), [0, 0]));
}

dirReduc([
  'NORTH',
  'NORTH',
  'NORTH',
  'SOUTH',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(;dx > 0; dx--){result.append('EAST');}
for(;dx < 0; dx++){result.append('WEST');}
for(;dy > 0; dy--){result.append('NORTH');}
for(;dy < 0; dy++){result.append('SOUTH');}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the switch statement you can use object mapping. The complexity od swirh is more than object mapping

```js
function dirReduc(arr) {
  var dx = 0;
  var dy = 0;
  var newArr = ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST"];
  switchObj = {
    NORTH: function() {
      console.log('north')
      dy++;
    },
    SOUTH: function() {
      console.log('SOUTH')
      dy--;
    },
    EAST: function() {
      console.log('EAST')
      dx++;
    },
    WEST: function() {
      console.log('WEST')
      dx--;
    }

  }
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    switchObj[arr[i]]();
  }
  //if () {}
}

dirReduc(["NORTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an object with the direction as property name and the values are arrays with 2 elements `[x, y]`. Use `reduce` to summarize the array.

```js
function dirReduc(arr) {
  var d = {NORTH: [0, 1],SOUTH: [0, -1],EAST: [1, 0],WEST: [-1, 0]}
  return arr.reduce(([x, y], v) => [x + d[v][0], y + d[v][1]], [0, 0]);
}

var result1 = dirReduc(['NORTH', 'SOUTH', 'NORTH', 'SOUTH']);
console.log('Result 1', result1);

var result2 = dirReduc(['NORTH', 'SOUTH', 'EAST', 'EAST','SOUTH']);
console.log('Result 2', result2);
```

UPDATE:

```js
function dirReduc(arr) {
  var d = {NORTH: [0, 1],SOUTH: [0, -1],EAST: [1, 0],WEST: [-1, 0]}


  return arr.reduce(([x, y], v) => [x + d[v][0], y + d[v][1]], [0, 0])
    .reduce((x, y) => [x > 0 ? 'EAST' : (x < 0 ? 'WEST' : 0), y > 0 ? 'NORTH' : (y < 0 ? 'SOUTH' : 0)]);
}

var result1 = dirReduc(['NORTH', 'SOUTH', 'NORTH', 'SOUTH']);
console.log('Result 1', result1);

var result2 = dirReduc(['NORTH', 'SOUTH', 'EAST', 'EAST', 'SOUTH']);
console.log('Result 2', result2);
```

Comment: That all makes sense; however, to satisfy the challenge the resulting array needs to be in the form of a string rather than [x,y] coordinates.

Comment: You can do like `var x = result1[0];` and `var y = result1[1];`

Comment: What is the format of return value do you prefer? @wellington

Comment: The format should be the same as the array passed in dirReduc(). Ex: ['North', 'West']

Comment: What does [0,0] represent inside the reduce method?

Comment: Ohh okay, One question though, What will be the string array for `[2,-3]`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173834/discussion-between-wellington-and-eddie).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const map = {
  NORTH: ([x, y]) => [x, y + 1],
  SOUTH: ([x, y]) => [x, y - 1],
  EAST: ([x, y]) => [x + 1, y],
  WEST: ([x, y]) => [x - 1, y],
};

const walk = coords => coords.reduce((tmp, x) => map[x](tmp), [0, 0])

const removeLoops = steps => {
  let loops = []
  for (var i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < steps.length; j++) {
      if (walk(steps.slice(i, j+1)) == '0,0') {
        loops.push([i, j])
        i = j
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  let newSteps = Array.from(steps)
  loops.reverse().forEach(([from, to]) => {
    newSteps.splice(from, to - from + 1)
  })
  return newSteps
}

console.log(removeLoops([
  'NORTH',
  'NORTH',
  'NORTH',
  'SOUTH',
]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something working

```
const arr = ['NORTH', 'SOUTH', 'WEST', 'NORTH', 'EAST', 'WEST', 'NORTH', 'SOUTH', 'EAST', 'WEST', 'NORTH', 'EAST', 'WEST'];

const os = {
  'EAST': 'WEST',
  'WEST': 'EAST',
  'NORTH': 'SOUTH',
  'SOUTH': 'NORTH'
}

const dc = arr.reduce((ds, d) => ({
  ...ds,
  [d]: (ds[d] || 0) + 1,
  [os[d]]: ds[os[d]] - 1
}), {});

const result = Object.keys(dc).filter(key => dc[key] > 0);

console.log(result)
```